C++ CMake Project: Issues Including External Library Header Files
I'm trying to use an external library (SerialSDK) in my C++ CMake project. My project structure looks like this:
project/
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include/
│   └── SerialSDK.h
├── src/
│   └── main.cpp
└── lib/
    ├── SerialSDK.lib
    ├── SerialSDK.dll
    └── SerialSDK.pdb

To integrate this library, I added the following lines to my CMakeLists.txt:
find_library(SERIAL_SDK_LIB NAMES SerialSDK PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

# Link against the SerialSDK library
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets ${SERIAL_SDK_LIB})

However, when I try to include the header file in my main.cpp like this:
#include "SerialSDK.h"

I encounter the following compilation error:
error: C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'BOOL'

Here's a snippet from the SerialSDK.h file:
#ifndef _SERIAL_H_
#define _SERIAL_H_
#define SERIAL_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

#define SERIAL_PORT_SDK_VERSION_V10 0x10
...
typedef struct tagSERIAL_PORT_SERIAL_ADDRESS
{
    WORD    wHostAddress;    // Host address (sender)
    BYTE    byRes[2];
    WORD    wBeginAddress;   // Receiver begin address
    WORD    wEndAddress;     // Receiver end address
    BYTE    byRes2[8];
} SERIAL_PORT_SERIAL_ADDRESS, *LPSERIAL_PORT_SERIAL_ADDRESS;

It seems like the compiler isn't recognizing some types (e.g., BOOL, WORD, BYTE). I suspect it might be related to missing or incorrect includes in the header file, or possibly an issue with my CMake configuration.
Could anyone help me figure out what's wrong and how to fix it? Thanks!

"I suspect it might be related to missing or incorrect includes in the header file" - Yes, the error most likely indicates that. But since we don't now which header is expected to contain the definition of type BOOL for SerialSDK.h header, we cannot help you. It could be that QT provides some header which is included by SerialSDK.h instead of the desired one. So you first step could be eliminating from your project all other include directories. You may also consult the documentation for SerialSDK project.

@Tsyvarev how can I ensure that the linking of the library is correctly done?

You got the error on the compiling stage. Linking stage has not performed yet, so it couldn't be the reason of your problem.

Your SerialSDK.h appears to require Windows API type definitions, but doesn't include the required headers themselves.
The types BOOL, BYTE, DWORD, etc. in the Windows API are defined in BaseTsd.h, which you can include either via
#include <BaseTsd.h>

or
#include <windows.h>

Use the latter if you want to use other parts of the Windows API and not just these type definitions.
The most correct fix would be to add that include to SerialSDK.h at the very top (because that header file requires that) directly after the include guard - but since this is an external library and you typically don't want to touch that, you can also change your own code to have the include statement for the Windows API before the include statement for the external library:
#include <BaseTsd.h>
#include <SerialSDK.h>

In that case the Windows API types will have been correctly defined before the definitions of SerialSDK.h are being processed.
You should probably also contact the vendor of the external library and ask them to add the missing include to the next version of that library, so that this problem disappears in the future.

Trying to find out which header file defines BOOL and add it to the include directory in CMake.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
